# Java instanceof implements/extends

Tags: java, instanceof

How does instanceof work exactly? When I have a hierarchy of objects that extend and implement eachother, does being instance of something work through these both lines?

For example I want to know if my object is instance of `List`or `ArrayList` or `Collection`?

I examined this tree, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html

And they seem to fall all under `Object` ofcourse, but what I need, I think is `AbstractCollection` or even normal `Collection` , because that seems to be the highest in hierarchy.

Will I be fine, when I check an object against only `Collection` to cover all those 3 classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will I be fine, when I check an object against only Collection to cover all those 3 classes?

Yes, `instanceof Collection` will return true for all implementation (direct or indirect) of the Collection interface.

In the rare case that you do not want this, you'd have to use reflection. For example, [Class#getDeclaredClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses%28%29) will give you a list of all classes and interfaces that are directly extended/implemented by the class.

Once you know that something is a Collection, you can cast it to get access to its methods (like `iterator`):

```
  if (myObject instanceof Collection){
      Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) myObject;
      for (Object o: c){
         // do something with every element in the collection
      }
  }
```

Comment: ok after getting returned true, can I somehow retrieve the first item, do they have a generic method I can use, because since they are `instanceof Collection`, I should be able to use `iterator.next()`

Comment: Oh, you want to iterate *all* classes that implement Collection? There is no real way to do that. What do you need that for?

Comment: Or do you want the "tree" of classes and interfaces that your class X inherits from? That you can do via reflection: Class#getClasses http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses%28%29

Comment: First I want to check if I am getting somekind of array, for example as I said `List` , `ArrayList` etc. If that is true, I want to take the first element and check if that is instanceof `MyClass`. Thats why I wanted to use iterator...to get the first element. Is that possible?

Comment: Okay, in this case, you'd do `instanceof Collection` and if it is, then you do a cast: `Collection c = (Collection)theObject;` and then you can do `c.iterator()` and work with that.

Comment: Oh nice, thats what I did myself, I was just wondering if all `Collection` objects can handle that iterator command.

Comment: They'd better handle iterators, because that is a non-optional method of the Collection interface. This is exactly what Java's strong typing gives you: assurances that certain objects have certain methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(obj instanceof Collection)
```

Will return true if the object is any kind of collection. So it will return true for your 3 cases, however it will also return true for other cases such as HashMap

Answer (score 1):

> Will I be fine, when I check an object against only Collection to cover all those 3 classes?

Not always.

It is possible that an object `is-a` a `Collection` but `ArrayList`.

For example:

```
ArrayList anArrList = new ArrayList();
HashMap ahashMap = new HashMap();

anArrList instanceof Collection // true
ahashMap instanceof Collection // true
```

but both are in different hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` operator will return `true` if the inspected object is a class or subclass of a given class or if it (or one of its ancestors) implements a given interface.